# Sufficient to show the cases when $x = 0$, $y=0$, and $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> For a fixed $k \in \mathbb{N}$, define $f_k: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by:
> $$
> f_k(x,y)=
> \begin{cases}
> \dfrac{x^2(x+y^2)}{x^2+y^{2k}} &, (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\
> 0 &, (x,y)=(0,0)\\
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Show that $f_1$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$, but $f_k$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ for each $k\geq 2$.
>
> (Hint: At some point it may help to separately consider the cases $|x|\geq |y|^k$ and $|x|\leq |y|^k$.)

So I was able to determine that if $f_k$ is differentiable, the derivative is $(1,0)$. So after some algebra, I see that I have to show that

$\left|\dfrac{x^2y^{2} - x y^{2k}}{(x^2 + y^{2k})\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right| \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

When evaluating this limit, is it sufficient to show the cases when $x = 0$, $y=0$, and $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far you have shown that
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}|\frac{f_k(x,y)-f_k(0,0)-\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial x}(0,0)x-\frac{\partial f_k}{\partial y}(0,0)y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|=\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}|\frac{x^2y^2-xy^{2k}}{(x^2+y^{2k})\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|$$

The function is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if and only if the above limit is zero.

Note that for the case $k=1$ the function $f_1$ indeed isn't differentiable since along the path $x=y$ we have
$$\lim\limits_{(y,y)\to(0,0)}|\frac{x^2y^2-xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|=\lim\limits_{(y,y)\to(0,0)}|\frac{y^4-y^3}{2\sqrt2y^3}|=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\neq0$$

Now suppose that $k\geq2$. Then, using the standard inequality $|\frac{x-y}{2}|\leq\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}$, we have
$$|\frac{x^2y^2-xy^{2k}}{(x^2+y^{2k})\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|\leq\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{x^4y^4+x^2y^{4k}}{(x^2+y^{2k})^2(x^2+y^2)}}\leq\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{x^2y^4(x^2+y^{2k})}{(x^2+y^{2k})^2(x^2+y^2)}}\leq\sqrt{2}|y|$$
and so
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}|\frac{x^2y^2-xy^{2k}}{(x^2+y^{2k})\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|\leq\lim\limits_{y\to0}\sqrt{2}|y|=0,$$
i.e. $f_k$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ for $k\geq2$.
$$$$

Comment: That's a wonderful solution, thank you. But I'm still concerned with the question I posed. Is it wrong for me to only consider the cases I mentioned? I guess my question has to do more with multivariable limits.

Comment: @user439126, I'm not sure that I got your question. You need to show that either the limit is zero along any path (the function is differentiable in that case) or that there exists a path with a non-zero limit (the function isn't differentiable in that case). Yes, theoretically you can break it into a separate cases of approaching the origin along the $x$-axis, $y$-axis and a random path not lying on any of the axes, however, this seems to be an overkill and will unnecessary obfuscate the solution.

Comment: The reason I ask is that I want to know if this can work in general for other multivariable limits. I just thought that to assume both $x \ne 0$ and $y \ne 0$ is to ignore a bunch of potential paths approaching $(0,0)$ where $x$ and $y$ can be $0$ (not at the same time), like a spiral.

Comment: Also, for your proof, how did you get to the last part of your inequality? It looks like you dropped $y^{2k}$ and $x^2$ is the denominator, but how do you know neither of them are $0$?

Comment: @user439126, note that $\frac{x^2y^4(x^2+y^{2k})}{(x^2+y^{2k})^2(x^2+y^2)}=\frac{x^2y^4}{(x^2+y^{2k})(x^2+y^2)}\leq\frac{x^2y^4}{x^2y^2}=y^2$

Comment: How do you know that $x$ or $y$ are not zero?

Comment: @user439126, if one of them is zero, then trivially you have a zero in the numerator, so the limit is also a zero.